# Help solving part B!

Tags: probability

A multiple choice test consists of 100 questions. Each question has 5 possible answers, only one of which is correct. Four points are awarded for each correct answer, and 1 point is taken off for each wrong answer. Suppose you answer all the questions by guessing at random, independently of all other questions.
A)In order to score more than 30 points, you have to get more than ***_*_** answers right. Fill in the blank with the smallest correct whole number
B)What is the chance that you get more than 30 points?

Solution to A:
A) x is the number of correct questions
4x - (100-x) > 30,
5x - 100 > 30,
5x > 130,
x > 26

Solution to B: 
?????????

Answer (score 4):

Hint: How many outcomes are there where you score more than 30 points?

How many outcomes are there total?

Comment: I do not know what you mean

Comment: You can think of each outcome as the number of test questions correctly answered. With this in mind, what are the possible outcomes (i.e., what are the possible values for "questions correctly answered"?) How many are there? Similarly, outcomes (again, number of tests questions answered correctly) yield a score of 30 or more? How many are there? (Hint 2: your answer to part (A) helps!)

Comment: When P(right)=0.20, X=number of corrects ~ binomial(100,0.20) and then P(X>=26) = 1-P(X<=25) = 1- binomCDF(25,100,0.2) = 0.08747538 but it is not correct

Comment: I found it correct answer is 0.0583

Answer (score 0):

All above is correct, except you ar calculating for 26 or more correct, the question truly wants 27 or more correct which leads to the answer of 0.05583.  The above 0.0585 is incorrect.